# Non-static method getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int) cannot be referenced from a static context?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How do you call getIntExtra from the override of **onResume()**?

Code that errors is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
     super.onResume();
     setDDL_Selected(0);
     setDDL_Selected(Intent.getIntExtra("DDL_ID", 0));
}
```

The compiler throws the following error:

> Non-static method getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int) cannot be
>   referenced from a static context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use:

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("DDL_ID", 0));
```

All `Activity`'s have a `getIntent()` method, which will return the `Intent` used to launch the `Activity`. By calling `getIntent()` you get an instance of an `Intent`, and you can call non-static methods on them

Comment: thanks, still learning! Will accept when it allows me. Thanks for the explanation too, makes sense now :-)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call the method `getIntExtra` on the class object, you need the intent instance. You can get it via [`Activity.getIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

I know you have an answer but you do not have to use getIntent() everywhere, best practice is to create Intent variable and initialize it in onCreate method then you can use every where in your activity.

```
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layoutname);
    intent=getIntent();
}
```

now use it like this:

```
setDDL_Selected(intent.getIntExtra("DDL_ID", 0));
```

Perhaps this is where you have encountered **Intent.getIntExtra** before?